# Thinking Sphinx - How to give different weights to models when searching multiple models (global search)

Tags: thinking-sphinx

Let say I have two indexed models: User and Student.

I want to search on both models but give precedence to User. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
results = ThinkingSphinx.search(search_term,
  :classes => [User, Student],
  :index_weights => {'user_core' => 5},
)
```

student_core will implicitly have a weight of 1.